# Matching one set of values to another in a text file

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a text file with this information:

```
1961 - Roger (Male)
1962 - Roger (Male)
1963 - Roger (Male)
1963 - Jessica (Female)
1964 - Jessica (Female)
1965 - Jessica (Female)
1966 - Jessica (Female)
```

If I want to search for the word "Roger" in the file, I want it to print out the corresponding years for that name, that is 1961, 1962, 1963. What would be the best way to approach this?

I was doing it with a dictionary but then realized later that dictionaries can't have duplicate values and 1963 is mentioned twice in the text file so it didn't work.

I'm using Python 3, thanks.

Comment: Use a `collections.defaultdict(list)` where the key is the name (possibly + the sex) and the years are appended to the corresponding value which will automatically start out as an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary with the name as the key and store the years in a list:

```
In [1]: with open("data1.txt") as f:
   ...:     dic={}
   ...:     for line in f:
   ...:         spl=line.split()
   ...:         dic.setdefault(spl[2],[]).append(int(spl[0]))
   ...:     for name in dic :    
   ...:         print (name,dic[name])
   ...:       

Roger [1961, 1962, 1963]
Jessica [1963, 1964, 1965, 1966]
```

or you can also use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
In [2]: from collections import defaultdict

In [3]: with open("data1.txt") as f:
   ...:     dic=defaultdict(list)
   ...:     for line in f:
   ...:         
   ...:         spl=line.split()
   ...:         dic[spl[2]].append(int(spl[0]))
   ...:     for name in dic:    
   ...:         print name,dic[name]
   ...:         
Roger [1961, 1962, 1963]
Jessica [1963, 1964, 1965, 1966]
```

Comment: Once again you are of great help Ashwini. It works, however, some names in the actual file I have, have middle names, so spl[2] doesn't work all the time. I did line.split('-') instead to fix that issue, but it always produces a "\n" at the end of each line, any idea why?

Comment: @Goose you can get read of that `\n` by using `strip()`, or simply `line.strip('\n').split('-')`.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use a dict and index on name (eg. `Roger`) as key and have values as a list of years (here `[1961,1962,1963]` ? would that not work for you?

so at the end of the loop you get all names uniquified with the years as values which is what you seem to want.

Comment: I tried using the dict method, so I had keys as the years, and values as the names, when I searched the dict for values matching "Roger" it came up with 1961, 1962 but not 1963 because Jessica shares that year as well.

Comment: have "roger" as keys and "years" as values. then it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Use [tuples](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).  They can be stored in lists, and iterated over.

Say your list looks like this:

```
data = [(1961, 'Rodger', 'Male'),
        (1962, 'Rodger', 'Male'),
        (1963, 'Rodger', 'Male'),
        (1963, 'Jessica', 'Female')]
```

You can run queries on it like this:

```
# Just items where the name is Rodger
[(y, n, s) for y, n, s in data if n == "Rodger"]

# Just the year 1963
[(y, n, s) for y, n, s in data if y == 1963]
```

---

Or use more Pythonic code:

```
for year, name, sex in data:
    if year >= 1962:
        print "In {}, {} was {}".format(year, name, sex)
```

> In 1962, Rodger was Male
>   In 1963, Rodger was Male
>   In 1963, Jessica was Female

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a regular expression.

```
import re

f = open('names.txt')
name = 'Roger'

for line in f.readlines():
    match = re.search(r'([0-9]+) - %s' % name, line)
    if match:
        print match.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in the comments:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
with open('data.txt', 'rt') as input:
    for line in input:
        year, person = [item.strip() for item in line.split('-')]
        result[person].append(year)

for person, years in result.items():
    print(person, years, sep=': ')
```

Output:

```
Roger (Male): ['1961', '1962', '1963']
Jessica (Female): ['1963', '1964', '1965', '1966']
```